# Performing a System Usability Scale test

Tags: sus

I want to perform a System Usability Scale test on two different designs of an application. I already found [this](http://usabilitygeek.com/how-to-use-the-system-usability-scale-sus-to-evaluate-the-usability-of-your-website/) link to a description and a rough explanation on how to do so, but what exactly is meant by this:

> First experience your website, and then // Second participate in the SUS.

The application basically supports only one scenario that can be performed with it, so do I give the participants a brief overview about the application, let them perform the single scenario and given them the questionnaire afterwards? I cannot find any "practical guide" either.

Answer (score 2):

The SUS is given to people who have used your product in some way.  Your method of having them perform their task and then administer the SUS is a perfectly valid application of the SUS.  It's very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

In practice you:

1. Let people use your application doing one or more tasks that you want them to successfully complete.
2. Survey the people who used the application and calculate a SUS score.

I got tired of creating forms and doing SUS calculations and created a simple application to help doing System Usability Scale Surveys. You get a survey link and and a respondent link which you can email to participants. Score is calculated automatically. Available for free with the hope that it will contribute to better usability: http://www.userpoll.io/